# Axios GET Request to JSON

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to use axios to get data from my API and to display it on a datatable on vue.js.

Here is my code in TypeScript :

```
import Vue from "vue"
import axios from 'axios'
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Magasin_Tables',
    data: () => ({
      search: '',
      headers: [
        { text: 'Code CAR', value: 'code'},
        { text: 'Libellé CAR', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'CAC de rattachement', value: 'linkedCac.code' },
        { text: 'Code du CAC', value: 'linkedCac.name' },
      ],
      magasins : null,
    }),
    created(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:8090/api/cars')
        .then(response => this.magasins = JSON.parse(response.data))
    }
})
```

I already tried without the JSON.parse(), and with a beforeCreate() but my magasins variable doesn't exist.

Here is my JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "W025",
    "name": "CAR BARCELONA",
    "linkedCac": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "W075",
      "name": "CAC ZARAGOZA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "code": "W002",
    "name": "CAR BOUC BEL AIR",
    "linkedCac": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "W075",
      "name": "CAC ZARAGOZA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "code": "W035",
    "name": "CAR GETAFE",
    "linkedCac": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "W075",
      "name": "CAC ZARAGOZA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "code": "W059",
    "name": "CAR CESTAS",
    "linkedCac": {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "W075",
      "name": "CAC ZARAGOZA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "code": "W043",
    "name": "CAR BASIANO",
    "linkedCac": {
      "id": 6,
      "code": "W043B",
      "name": "CAC BASIANO"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "code": "W051",
    "name": "CAR BOLOGNA",
    "linkedCac": {
      "id": 6,
      "code": "W043B",
      "name": "CAC BASIANO"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is my code for the table :

```
<v-container fluid>
    <v-card
    style="margin-top: 2vh;">
      <v-row
      justify='space-between'
        ><v-card-title
        style="margin-left: 2vh;">
          Récapitulatif des magasins
        </v-card-title>
      <v-btn
      style="margin-right: 4vh; margin-top: 2vh;"
      color='primary'
      href='/magasins/import'>
        Importer des magasins
      </v-btn>
      </v-row>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
        style="margin: 2vh;"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="magasins" :search="search"></v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
```

Do someone have any idea how to change my TypeScript file to display data on my table?

Comment: You may have an error coming back from the api. Can you check this by adding .catch to the axios promise. .catch(error => console.log(error)) https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors and if there is output add it to your question

Comment: If I print the response from the API, the JSON displays on the console. It's not from the API

Comment: So I've just replicated your code and it works my side, when removing JSON.parse so maybe there is an issue in your template? Can you show me how you are logging your output from the API and how you are using it in your display table.

Comment: Yes the API request is working. I just can't add the data in my table.

Comment: Can you show me the code for your table please

Comment: I edited my post to add table code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem appears to be due to the type conversion of magasins. You need to change the type of it which it is empty slice

```
data: () => ({
      search: '',
      headers: [
        {text: 'Code CAR', value: 'code'},
        { text: 'Libellé CAR', value: 'name' },
        { text: 'CAC de rattachement', value: 'linkedCac.code' },
        { text: 'Code du CAC', value: 'linkedCac.name' },
      ],
      magasins: [], // Change this from null
    }),
```

And ensure you do not use `JSON.parse`

```
created() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8090/api/cars')
      .then(response => this.magasins = response.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on component `creation` time the data does not exist yet.

Use `mounted` instead of `created` for using Axios in a component.

Comment: Still doesn't work with mounted(). Do I have the right syntax to get my datas and to displays them on the table ?